# How to search specific files from two folders and compare timestamp if the same or what is the newest files given using Batch Windows Scripting

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, scripting

I have initial code for searching and comparing in ALL files:

```
SET FILE1=Directory1\* 
SET FILE2=Directory2\* 


FOR %%i IN (%FILE1%) DO SET DATE1=%%~ti
FOR %%i IN (%FILE2%) DO SET DATE2=%%~ti
IF "%DATE1%"=="%DATE2%" ECHO Files have same age && GOTO END

FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B /O:D %FILE1% %FILE2%') DO SET NEWEST=%%i
ECHO Newer file is %NEWEST%

:END
```

How do specifically search based on the directory that this certain file name should be search and compare?

Sample:
I want to search all specific like INV and SLS file in its name and compare if the same or what is the newest file:

in Directory1:

```
Flatfile           Timestamp
-------           ----------
INVF032            3/14/2019
INVF021            3/14/2019
KVNF234            3/14/2019
SLS0234            3/14/2019
SLS3211            3/14/2019
```

in Directory2:

```
Flatfile           Timestamp
-------           ----------
INVF032            3/19/2019
INVF021            3/19/2019
KVNF234            3/19/2019
SLS0234            3/19/2019
SLS3211            3/19/2019
```

**Output:**

```
Newer files is:
INVF032            3/19/2019
INVF021            3/19/2019
SLS0234            3/19/2019
SLS3211            3/19/2019
```

Adding some echo on errors in the output after running in Windows Server 2008(It says instance not available):

```
C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>sample.bat

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>rem // Author: KJSaycon: Batch Script Code for JDE Flat
file Extraction version 1

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>echo "Program is running. ."
"Program is running. ."

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>rem // Defining the constant variables and pointers:

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>set "_ROOT=C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\."   & rem // (set
root directory; `C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\.` means is script's parent directory,
 `.` means current PATH)

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>set "_DIR1=C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\.\fp_files1\"   & r
em // (1st directory containing files)

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>set "_DIR2=C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\.\fp_files2\"   & r
em // (2nd directory containing files)

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>set _MASKS="*INV*" "*SLS*" "*PUR*"      & rem // (list
of quoted file masks, find string like *char*)

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>set "_TMP1=C:\Users\ksaycon\AppData\Local\Temp\179\samp
le_1_27853.tmp"   & rem // (set temp file 1)

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>set "_TMP2=C:\Users\ksaycon\AppData\Local\Temp\179\samp
le_2_15411.tmp"   & rem // (set temp file 2)

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>rem // Loop 1st directory to be an absolute path:

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>for %E in ("C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\.\fp_files1\") do
set "RDIR1=%~fE"

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>set "RDIR1=C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\fp_files1\"

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>rem // Loop 2nd directory to be an absolute path:

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>for %E in ("C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\.\fp_files2\") do
set "RDIR2=%~fE"

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>set "RDIR2=C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\fp_files2\"

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>rem // Write all matching files in 1st directory to 1st
 temporary file using assembly language function PUSHD:

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>pushd "C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\fp_files1\"   && (
for %F in ("*INV*" "*SLS*" "*PUR*") do (echo(%~nxF )
 popd
) 1>"C:\Users\ksaycon\AppData\Local\Temp\179\sample_1_27853.tmp"

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>rem // Write all matching files in 2nd directory to 2nd
 temporary file using assembly language function PUSHD:

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>pushd "C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\fp_files2\"   && (
for %F in ("*INV*" "*SLS*" "*PUR*") do (echo(%~nxF )
 popd
) 1>"C:\Users\ksaycon\AppData\Local\Temp\179\sample_2_15411.tmp"

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>rem // Loop over all common files from both temporary f
iles:

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>for /F %L in ('findstr /L /I /X /G:"C:\Users\ksaycon\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\179\sample_1_27853.tmp" "C:\Users\ksaycon\AppData\Local\Temp\17
9\sample_2_15411.tmp"') do (
rem // Build absolute `wmic`-compatible file paths:
 set "FILE1=C:\\Users\\ksaycon\\Desktop\\fp_files1\\\\%L"   & set "FILE2=C:\\Use
rs\\ksaycon\\Desktop\\fp_files2\\\\%L"
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 rem set "FILE1=&=&amp;!" & set "FILE2=&=&amp;!"
 rem // Loop to get standardised file date/time (last modification) of 1st file
by `wmic`:
 for /F "skip=1" %K in ('wmic DataFile where "Name='!FILE1!'" get LastModified')
 do for /F %K in ("%K") do set "DATE1=%K"
 rem // Loop to get standardised file date/time (last modification) of 2nd file
by `wmic`:
 for /F "skip=1" %K in ('wmic DataFile where "Name='!FILE2!'" get LastModified')
 do for /F %K in ("%K") do set "DATE2=%K"
 rem // If Compare file dates/times (last mod.) of both files and return differi
ng ones:
 if !DATE1! LSS !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is older than "!FILE2:\\=\!"
 if !DATE1! GTR !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is newer than "!FILE2:\\=\!"
 if !DATE1! EQU !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" and "!FILE2:\\=\!" are of same age

 endlocal
)

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>(
rem // Build absolute `wmic`-compatible file paths:
 set "FILE1=C:\\Users\\ksaycon\\Desktop\\fp_files1\\\\FFPDFINV01"   & set "FILE2
=C:\\Users\\ksaycon\\Desktop\\fp_files2\\\\FFPDFINV01"
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 rem set "FILE1=&=&amp;!" & set "FILE2=&=&amp;!"
 rem // Loop to get standardised file date/time (last modification) of 1st file
by `wmic`:
 for /F "skip=1" %K in ('wmic DataFile where "Name='!FILE1!'" get LastModified')
 do for /F %K in ("%K") do set "DATE1=%K"
 rem // Loop to get standardised file date/time (last modification) of 2nd file
by `wmic`:
 for /F "skip=1" %K in ('wmic DataFile where "Name='!FILE2!'" get LastModified')
 do for /F %K in ("%K") do set "DATE2=%K"
 rem // If Compare file dates/times (last mod.) of both files and return differi
ng ones:
 if !DATE1! LSS !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is older than "!FILE2:\\=\!"
 if !DATE1! GTR !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is newer than "!FILE2:\\=\!"
 if !DATE1! EQU !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" and "!FILE2:\\=\!" are of same age

 endlocal
)
No Instance(s) Available.

"  do set "DATE1=Desktop>for /F %K in ("
No Instance(s) Available.

"  do set "DATE2=Desktop>for /F %K in ("
"C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\fp_files1\\FFPDFINV01" and "C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop\f
p_files2\\FFPDFINV01" are of same age

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>rem // Clean up temporary files:

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>del "C:\Users\ksaycon\AppData\Local\Temp\179\sample_1_2
7853.tmp" "C:\Users\ksaycon\AppData\Local\Temp\179\sample_2_15411.tmp"

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>echo "Clearing up garbage collection! Done."
"Clearing up garbage collection! Done."

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>endlocal

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>exit /B

C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop>
```

Comment: Do you just want to know what the latest file (of specific names) is in either directory?

Comment: With regards your example output, what's the benefit in showing filenames with dates, surely you need to know, which directory holds each too!

Comment: As batch has no datetime variable type comparing dates (which are locale/user settings dependent) isn't that easy, I suggest using powershell for this.

Comment: I was trying this to workout with a specific program in JDE AS/400 in the server, here's the thing why I am asking that:

The flatfiles are being uploaded with a batch script in the server (Extractions) and they are uploaded one time (not in sequential uploading), so there is no way you could determine if the file was uploaded. Now the only logic I can think of is comparing the two folders with the specific files and if the newest is the uploaded ftp folder then the process of uploading will stop.

Comment: @aschipfl edited with the echo on, seems like the path was ok, when running in the windows server 2008 it says instances not available, and I turned on the echo and I see the the debug marks near delete temp. Can you think there maybe compatible issues with the code in set date? Thanks

Comment: No, I don't know about any such compatibility issues. Anyway, at first, I'd try not to append `\ `when setting `_DIR1` and `_DIR2`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intention is not quite clear, particularly because your desired output is ambiguous as it does not contain the parent directories of the files.

Anyway, here is a script that does what you want (at least for my understanding), given that only files that are present in both directories are to be processed.

So this is the code, containing several explanatory `rem`-remarks:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0." & rem // (common root directory; `%~dp0.` is script's parent, `.` is current)
set "_DIR1=%_ROOT%\Directory1" & rem // (1st directory containing files)
set "_DIR2=%_ROOT%\Directory2" & rem // (2nd directory containing files)
set _MASKS="INV*." "SLS*."     & rem // (list of quoted file masks)
set "_TMP1=%TEMP%\%~n0_1_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (1st temporary file)
set "_TMP2=%TEMP%\%~n0_2_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (2nd temporary file)

rem // Resolve 1st directory to be an absolute path:
for %%E in ("%_DIR1%") do set "RDIR1=%%~fE"
rem // Resolve 2nd directory to be an absolute path:
for %%E in ("%_DIR2%") do set "RDIR2=%%~fE"

rem // Write all matching files in 1st directory to 1st temporary file:
pushd "%RDIR1%" && (
    for %%F in (%_MASKS%) do (
        echo(%%~nxF
    )
    popd
) > "%_TMP1%"
rem // Write all matching files in 2nd directory to 2nd temporary file:
pushd "%RDIR2%" && (
    for %%F in (%_MASKS%) do (
        echo(%%~nxF
    )
    popd
) > "%_TMP2%"

rem // Loop over all common files from both temporary files:
for /F %%L in ('findstr /L /I /X /G:"%_TMP1%" "%_TMP2%"') do (
    rem // Build absolute `wmic`-compatible file paths:
    set "FILE1=%RDIR1:\=\\%\\%%L" & set "FILE2=%RDIR2:\=\\%\\%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem set "FILE1=%!FILE1:&=&amp;!" & set "FILE2=%!FILE2:&=&amp;!"
    rem // Get standardised file date/time (last modification) of 1st file by `wmic`:
    for /F "skip=1" %%K in ('wmic DataFile where "Name='!FILE1!'" get LastModified') do for /F %%K in ("%%K") do set "DATE1=%%K"
    rem // Get standardised file date/time (last modification) of 2nd file by `wmic`:
    for /F "skip=1" %%K in ('wmic DataFile where "Name='!FILE2!'" get LastModified') do for /F %%K in ("%%K") do set "DATE2=%%K"
    rem // Compare file dates/times (last mod.) of both files and return differing ones:
    if !DATE1! leq !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is older than "!FILE2:\\=\!"
    if !DATE1! gtr !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" is newer than "!FILE2:\\=\!"
    if !DATE1! equ !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" and "!FILE2:\\=\!" are of same age
    endlocal
)

rem // Clean up temporary files:
del "%_TMP1%" "%_TMP2%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

The core commands are:

- [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), to return all files that are common in the two given directories;
- [`wmic`](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html), to retrieve the last modification dates/times of the files in a standardised manner (formatted like `YYYYMMDDhhmmss.uuuuuu+ZZZ`), which can be easily compared as strings;

Comment: how do I compare also if the dates for the  two files from two directories are the same? can you add a if else condition there based on your given code? Thanks

Comment: I thought this is quite obvious: `if !DATE1! equ !DATE2! echo "!FILE1:\\=\!" and "!FILE2:\\=\!" are of the same age`

Comment: tried to run that but seems like even assuming that DATE1 has date of March 3/19/2019 09:23 AM and DATE2 has date of March 3/19/2019 10:03 AM suppose that the expected output be that Date1 has older date with Date2 but in the output it says Date1 is the same date with Date2.

Comment: Thank youuu :) sorry had to post in the other section thought of you as inactive. Thankss agaiin

Comment: how do i set directory when it is in map network drive or in a network shared folder or in different local Disk?

`Sample:`
`Dir1 = D: \\JDAFTP_files\source_data\fp_files\JFPPRT2RE`
`Dir2 = \\206.101.216.22\i2FTP_Shared\dfil_datafiles`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to access UNC paths... perhaps search this site or [Super User](https://superuser.com/)...

Comment: in the given code above, I did update the code changes and how do I make a couter time out? Like I will give you scenario: Given the code t loops infinite when the Dir1 is eq Dir2 and it will stop looping once all files from Dir1 is updated  and newest to Dir2. Now in the infinite loop, I need some break statement if the infinte loops around like giving a 1 hour session to loop and if no updates after 1 hour it will stop, somewhat like a counter timeout to stop the looping after 1 hour. Is that possible or I need some another logic or suggestion you can have? Thanks

Comment: Please don't ask additional questions in comments, post a new (on-topic) question instead! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A PowerShell solution using LastWriteTime to compare.

```
$Dir1 = 'X:\Directory1\'
$Dir2 = 'X:\Directory2\'

ForEach ($File1 in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir1 -File | 
                    Where-Object Name -match "^(INV|SLS)")){
  $File2 = Join-Path $Dir2 $File1.Name
  If (Test-Path $File2 -NewerThan $File1.LastWriteTime){
    "File {0} is newer {1} in {2}" -f $File1.Name,(Get-Item $File2).LastWriteTime,$Dir2
  } else {
    "File {0} is newer {1} in {2}" -f $File1.Name,$File1.LastWriteTime,$Dir1 
  }
}
```

Sample output (with my locale datetime format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss):

```
File INVF021 is newer 2019-03-19 00:00:00 in X:\Directory2\
File INVF032 is newer 2019-03-19 00:00:00 in X:\Directory2\
File SLS0234 is newer 2019-03-19 00:00:00 in X:\Directory2\
File SLS3211 is newer 2019-03-19 00:00:00 in X:\Directory2\
```

Comment: question, how do I run this powershell script using a bat file? Thanks